# Why doesn't this load into https?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, https, requirehttps, requiressl

In asp.net mvc 3 I have a site which has an ssl certificate, and runs just fine in https. The only page exposed is the logon page. For whatever reason, it does not load in https. Here is my relevant code (will post more on request if I left something out).

web.config

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"  requireSSL="true"/>
</authentication>
```

global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
}
```

account controller

```
#if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps]
#endif
public class AccountController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When the logon view loads, it is not in Https. What did I miss?

Comment: Daft question I know, but are you running in debug mode?

Comment: @JohnH - :) Nope (or at least I am fairly certain not), see the included line in the web.config? `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I missed that. :)

Comment: @TravisJ - the web.config entry has nothing to do with the DEBUG symbol being defined when the site is compiled.  This is set in the Build Target settings of Visual Studio.

Comment: @MystereMan - Ah, you are correct! What should I edit in order to make #Debug be false in release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Build Target to Release when you build your site.  You will see a dropdown that looks like this in Visual Studio, change it to Release and rebuild, then publish your site:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This worked, thank you. I cannot believe I missed something so simple.

Comment: @TravisJ - Just remember, MVC is a Web Application project, which means all code is compiled to a dll at compile time.  The web pages (aspx or cshtml) are compiled at runtime still, but the .cs files are not, therefore you have to set the build target to release in order to get real release build.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice a difference in the .dll size when bin deploying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[RequireHttps]`, so it would look like this:

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will force it to use `Https`.

**Edit**

Perhaps you need to add, the following to your `Web.Config`'s `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Secure Account Controller" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^account" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:44300{URL}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Don't the action methods inherit the requirement from the controller?

Comment: Yes they do, what happens if you remove the `#if !DEBUG`? Sorry I didn't notice that. You can debug in `HTTPS` by using `localhost:44300` I think.

Comment: Oddly enough, removing the `#IF` directive makes the `[RequireHttps]` function properly. What would cause the IF to fail?

Comment: My guess is that the correct URL's aren't being rewritten. Try adding my edit to you're `Web.Config` file and seeing if that helps. I'm not sure because I have never used a `#If` in this situation.

Comment: @TravisJ You know you are saying `#if !DEBUG` so you should expect only release to run in `HTTPS` otherwise you should use `#if DEBUG` for Debug. However I doubt this is your issue.